# Master Detail Page is not appearing after Content page

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am working in xamarin.forms. I am creaing an android application. In my application I have to use menu. So I took Master detail page to show the menus. And its working fine.

But my problem is before showing the Master detail page, I have to open a content page which doesn't contain the menus. So I took a content page and set it. But when I am running the application after content page, Master detail page is not appearing. The code is running successfully but the Master page is not appearing.

Can any one tell me how I can show the Master detail page after showing simple content page?

Answer (score 2):

The answer will depend on if you want to maintain the navigation stack or not.  If you want to add the new page to the current Navigation Stack then you need to so something like this in the Content Page:

```
((NavigationPage)Parent).PushAsync(newPage);
```

If you want to make the new page the root of the Navigation Stack then you need to do something like this:

```
((App) Parent).MainPage = newPage;
```

If this doesn't work, post your code.

Comment: Thanks Christine, Its working now. I used App.Current.MainPage=newPage;

Answer (score 0):

Giving you a trick ! suppose you have a login page ,after authentication you will go to RootPage which is a masterDetailPage .

*Take a hint from from below code*

```
namespace LoginNavigation
{
    public class App : Application, IloginInterface
    {
        public static App current;
        public static bool IsUserLoggedIn { get; set; }
        public static double ScreenWidth;
        public static double ScreenHeight;

        public App () {
            current = this;
            MainPage = new LoginPageWithStack ();
        }

        public void Logout() {
            MainPage = new LoginPageWithStack ();
        }

        public void ShowMainPage() {
            MainPage = new RootPage ();
        }
    }
}
```

rootPage:

```
namespace LoginNavigation
{
    public class RootPage:MasterDetailPage
    {
        MenuPage menuPage;


        public RootPage () {
            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Filter", "ring.png", async () => {
                var page = new ContentPage();
                var result = await page.DisplayAlert("Title", "Message", "Accept", "Cancel");
                Debug.WriteLine("success: {0}", result);
            }));

            menuPage = new MenuPage ();

            menuPage.Menu.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => NavigateTo (e.SelectedItem as MenuItemForMaster);

            //Master = new MasterMenu();
            Master = menuPage;
            Detail = new NavigationPage (new TimeSheet()){
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("008dce"),BackgroundColor  = Color.FromHex("008dce")
            };
        }

        void NavigateTo (MenuItemForMaster menu) {
            if (menu == null)
                return;

            Page displayPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance (menu.TargetType);
            //Detail = displayPage;
            Detail = new NavigationPage (displayPage) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("008dce"),BackgroundColor  = Color.FromHex("008dce")};

            menuPage.Menu.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So the trick is ,get the current instance of App class and manipulate Mainpage property of it .

Comment: I tried it but still not working. Can you please update the specific code that I should write in App.cs so that I can move on master detail page after content pag.